# SQL custom grouping by value

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Ok so what I have is a list of counties. What I want to do is get the count of clients by county. However I only need three major counties and then group everything else into an 'Other' Category.

```
select county,COUNT(*)
from person
where person_id in (select distinct person_id from person_encounter)
and create_timestamp >= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-01')
and create_timestamp <= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-31')
group by county
```

Is what I have which gets me the count for all counties just fine. but how do I group The extras into 'Other'

Comment: You also probably need `and create_timestamp < '2015-09-01'`, if you want all of August in the results.

Comment: @ypercube That is eventually going to be replaced by a variable but yes you are correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
select 
    CASE county
        WHEN 'County1' THEN 'County1'
        WHEN 'County2' THEN 'County2'
        WHEN 'County3' THEN 'County3'
     ELSE 'Other' END AS County
    ,COUNT(*)
from person
where person_id in (select distinct person_id from person_encounter)
    and create_timestamp >= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-01')
    and create_timestamp <= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-31')
group by  
    CASE county
        WHEN 'County1' THEN 'County1'
        WHEN 'County2' THEN 'County2'
        WHEN 'County3' THEN 'County3'
     ELSE 'Other' END ;
```

Comment: When I run that I get the error: Cannot use an aggregate or a subquery in an expression used for the group by list of a GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 0):

How about a UNION of 2 queries 1st = your main 3 counties, 2nd = everything that isnt your main 3 counties

```
select county, COUNT(*)
from person
where person_id in (select distinct person_id from person_encounter)
and create_timestamp >= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-01')
and create_timestamp <= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-31')
and county in ('1','2','3')
group by county
UNION ALL
select 'other' AS county, COUNT(*)
from person
where person_id in (select distinct person_id from person_encounter)
and create_timestamp >= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-01')
and create_timestamp <= CONVERT(datetime,'2015-08-31')
and county not in ('1','2','3')
```